# Firefox saved password functionality. Can it be improved to handle two instances of the same account name & same domain, but different locations (i.e /one and /two) and different accounts?

Tags: firefox

This questions concerns Firefox 3.0.12 on Linux.

I have multiple Wordpress installs on one domain, let's call it *foo.com*. For this example I only need two, I have foo.com/one and foo.com/two. Both of these have their own database and their own Admin account.

The problem is that Firefox sees these two as the same account. If I regester `{Admin,Password}` for foo.com/two last it will suggest the /two password when I later am about to login at /one too.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer to your direct issue but Opera already does this.  When it asks to save a password you can tell it to save it for the current URL only (domain.com/path).

Comment: It's great to know, and thank you for answering! However I've come to depend on my specific set of extensions which I use. If there is nothing out there I'll look into how hard it would be to develop this kind of functionality as an extension myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different browser. Firefox developers have decided the current behavior (match domain + username) is the only way (which was different in Firefox 2.x). See the Firefox bugs:

[Bug 263387 passwords should be stored for host+path and not just host](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263387)

[Bug 444333 Password not saved for multiple login within same domain](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=444333)

[Bug 436275 wrong password filled in when same login is used for different forms](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436275)

All those bug reports are marked as "wontfix", meaning the developers think is not really a problem or is too hard to solve or it will create more problems.

The last bug report even includes a Javascript patch (which only works in Firefox 3.6) which changed the behavior of the password manager to match the domain + user field (not the username) but it could be modified to store the complete URL or anything else.

Finally, I don't know of any Firefox addon that allow to store the same username for the same domain for different sites/applications (at least not those addons which use the Firefox Password Manager, maybe those replacing or using an external password storage can do it).